# SQL Server 2008 and compatibility level 80

Tags: compatibility-level

Is there any technical reason why an application certified on SQL Server 2000 should not work properly on SQL Server 2008 with compatibility level 80?

In other words would there be any possible data or functionality loss in attaching a 2000 database to a 2008 server, keeping the 80 level?

Comment: Easy way to find out... give it a whirl. There are some default setting that are different however... and some new keywords that can cause issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory it should work.  You better test it thoroughly before converting production.  If your application uses DTS packages, they will have to be converted to SSIS.  Your OS will have changed as well, so double check to make sure your app does not rely on operating system level functionality.

To further answer your question, the vendor is likely not wanting to support it as a way of covering their butts.  They certified the application to run on SQL 2000, not SQL 2008.

I would stop giving them money if I were you.

Comment: So, assuming there are no DTS and that OS change and testing are already in scope, I can not understand why the vendor should not support it... That was my question